# Show there exists a non-commutative cancellative semigroup with generators $w,x$ satisfying $xwx=ww$

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, semigroups

Let $W$ be a cancellative semigroup and $w,x\in W$ non-identity elements such that $xwx=ww$ and $\{x,w\}$ generates $W$. Prove that $W$ is commutative or find a counterexample. (Note that $x=1,w=2,W=\mathbb{N}$ is a commutative example.)

Comment: Your example is using addition implicitly, you should indicate that you're assuming $+$ as your binary operation on $\Bbb{N}$

Comment: What is the origin of your question and what did you try to solve it?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin The origin of the question is adjoining solutions of product equations to cancellative semigroups. A product equation is an equation of the form $f(x)=g(x)$ where $f(x),g(x)$ are product functions, i.e. a product of factors consisting of constants and powers of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Answer was found on another website: $S_3$ with $x=(1\ 2)$ and $w=(1\ 2\ 3)$.